# Custom ReactTable <SelectTable> 'select all' checkbox column position and styling

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I've got a React table  which I've almost got working how I want it too

I'm using the selectAll props value which adds a checkbox to the tables header - the functionality is working fine

Is there a way to change the position of this checkbox? Say from the first column to now be the second column? And also I'd like to alter the mark up - current it is an `<input>` value but for my CSS styling it needs to be wrapped inside of a `<fieldset>`

I've gone through the documentation but couldn't find an out of the box solution, if anyone can point me in the correct direction that would be great